# How to configure settings.py in Django for MongoDB?

Tags: python, django, mongodb, django-nonrel, django-mongodb-engine

I have already completed a Django server installation and now I want to connect it to a MongoDB database. For that I changed my `settings.py` file of my project like this:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django_mongodb_engine', 
        'NAME': 'db_name',                   
        'USER': '',
        'PASSWORD': '',
        'HOST': '',                      
        'PORT': '',                      
    }
}
```

Now when I run in command prompt:

```
python manage.py runserver
```

it shows an error:

```
no module named django_mongodb_engine.base
```

How can I resolve this error?

Comment: there is a dedicated project because it seems there is no "native" support provided by django ; the project is [django-nonrel](http://django-nonrel.org/)

Comment: @FoxMaSk may you please tell what is use of mongodb-engine when we deal with django with no-rel database ?

Comment: django norel is a project that supports mongodb if this is your question. so after installing it, like you did, [the settings is the following](http://django-mongodb-engine.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/settings.html) hope this could help

Comment: @FoxMaSk i am using django 1.5 so think i don't need any third party fork for mongodb connection. what i want to know is how to configure settings.py in django project so that it would be connect with mongodb database and can fetch data of json type in django server.

Comment: I have crated a django 1.5.2 virtualenv and I think you need one third party as the error is when i did `python manage syncdb` : `django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: 'django_mongodb_engine' isn't an available database backend. And [the official documentation of django says.... no mongodb](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/databases/)
Try using 'django.db.backends.XXX', where XXX is one of:
    u'mysql', u'oracle', u'postgresql_psycopg2', u'sqlite3'`

Comment: and [the official documentation of django says.... no mongodb](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/databases/)

Answer (score 0):

Add the following code in settings.py file :-

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.dummy',
        'NAME': 'my-db',
    }
}
```